# Determining equation of least-squares line without data points

Tags: statistics, regression, descriptive-statistics, linear-regression

I am trying to determine the equation for the least-squares line graphed below only knowing that the same mean for the High School GPAs is x bar = 2.6, and the sample mean for the University GPAs is y bar = 3.05. I am unsure how to even go about this without having any data points to grab. The only part I managed to get is

intercept = 3.05-2.6*slope

Here is the image:

[image]

Thanks for any help with this. I can't even be sure this is possible to do with what I know. Thanks.

Comment: Can´t you read off the intercept from the graph ?

Comment: It's relatively easy to construct an artificial set of data that have the specified mean values but have any slope you want, even a negative slope. That's a fairly strong indication that just knowing the two means is not enough information. I don't think even the formula you wrote is guaranteed to be true; least squares gives a lot of weight to points far from the best-fit line, so a few data points with unusually high University GPA would pull up the line more than they would pull up the mean.

Comment: @callculus what do you mean? The graph starts at 2,2 so no, there is no visual representation of the intercept.

Comment: @DavidK This question was on my midterm-- word for word-- and I am trying to understand it. So it must be possible... I hope.

Comment: You can estimate the coordinates two points off the line on the graph and project that back to the y-axis. That's probably your best bet.

Comment: @DavidK No the bottom part is from me.

Comment: You are right that $b_0= \overline y-b_1\cdot \overline x$  This is one equation equation with two unknowns. There is no other choice than evaluating $b_0$ or $b_1$ from the graph if you have no additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read two points off the line as best you can and use the two-point form for the line.  Without a ruler, I see $(2,2.45)$ and $(4.5,3.95)$, but maybe you can be more accurate.  Put a line through them and you are done.

Comment: yep, plugged those into my equation and got the correct slope etc. Thanks a ton! Didn't know I could just guestimate points and get correct answers.